# Pycharm Kivy Serial Port Read

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I'm going to create a very simple Kivy application to read serial port and show it in a Label, in Python console i can see serial data but in Pycharm and Kivy the result is wrong.

[Result window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wugV4.jpg)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import serial
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)
    ser.read()
    super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = 2
    self.rows = 2
    self.add_widget(Label(text=str(ser)))
class MyApp(App):

  def build(self):
    return LoginScreen()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the serial object to `str`. That's why it's displaying like that - the string representation of the serial object.

```
self.add_widget(Label(text=str(ser)))
```

You should first read from the serial:

```
data = ser.read()
```

Now you can process this data or convert it to string and display on Kivy.

```
self.add_widget(Label(text=str(data)))
```